# Does ask pattern override message receive

Tags: scala, akka

I define the following messages and actors:

```
case class Message1(text: String)
case class Message2(text: String)
case class Message3(text: String)

class Actor1(actor2: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Message1(text) =>
            (actor2 ? Message2(text)).mapTo[Message3].foreach(self ! _)
        case Message3(text) =>
            println(s"Got the message[$sender]: " + text)
    }
}

class Actor2 extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case Message2(text) =>
            println(s"Actor2[$self] received: " + text)
            sender ! Message3("Received message1: " + text)
    }
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val system = ActorSystem("Test")
    system.actorOf(Props(new Actor1(system.actorOf(Props(new Actor2))))) ! Message1("Hello")
}
```

When I run this code the output when Message3 is received by Actor1 implies that it only receives the Message3 that is sent from within the Future.foreach and not the one sent back by Actor2 - as this is handled by the ask pattern.

So my question: is this always the expected behaviour?

Comment: if you want to send the Message3("received message1:" + text) to actor 1 use pipeTo sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is in fact the expected behavior.

The main purpose of ask is to create a dummy ActorRef that doesn't use as much resources as a fully-flegded actor to act as a sender that you can reply to.

It only wraps a promise that gets completed when a message is received and the future is returned from the ask function.

So, although you are technically asking from Actor1, the sender() in Actor2 will be the dummy PromiseActor that ask creates, that is why you don't receive Message2 from Actor2.

Answer (score 2):

`ask` (`?`) creates an internal actor to handle replies. In general, use `tell` (`!`) instead of `ask` for inter-actor communication:

```
class Actor1(actor2: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Message1(text) =>
      actor2 ! Message2(text)
    case Message3(text) =>
      println(s"Got the message[$sender]: $text")
  }
}
```